# Intel SGX Error: What does the 8207 error mean when I cannot load the enclave correct

Tags: c++, intel, sgx

I have made the following enclave & app loading the enclave:

https://github.com/pc-magas/myFirstEnclave/tree/run_fail

As you can see I load the wrong path of the enclave therefore the app fails to run as expected, when that happens in the example it returns the error:

> SGX error code: 8207
>
> Fail to initialize enclave.

But I cannot figure tour what does the `8207` error code means as far I can see I does not get mentioned over the error codes on documentation: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/709252

So can you explain what does this error code means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8207 (decimal) is 200F (hex), and your link shows:

```
0x200F | SGX_ERROR_ENCLAVE_FILE_ACCESS          | Can’t open enclave file.
```

Which is what you'd expect when passing the wrong path.